# no such option --system for pip install

Tags: amazon-web-services, pip, cron, serverless

I'm attempting to deploy a very basic trading system to AWS using serverless (following along with [this link](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-create-a-fully-automated-ai-based-trading-system-with-python-708503c1a907)), but I have a bit of a problem.

Prior to running the deployment command, I'm supposed to run

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt -t . --system
```

but I am getting an error message saying 'no such option: --system'

Initially, I just tried to install the packages without the --system option, but I think that's causing the cron lamda(??) function to fail when I execute it manually through the serverless console because it's not finding the requisite modules.

I'm assuming it's because they aren't being installed properly so my question is how then should I install them so this doesn't happen?

Running

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

alone (while in the trading system directory) does not suffice.

So, what should I do?

Comment: The [Pip Documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/) does not have any reference to a `--system` option. You might want to contact the author of that article and ask them about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original author was working on an older Debian-derived system, you aren't. You can safely omit this option if it's not supported.

I don't have an authoritative link available, although [this](https://matthew-brett.github.io/pydagogue/installing_on_debian.html) came up in a Google search. But here's my summary:

- With older Debian-derived systems (eg, Ubuntu 18.04), the `--user` flag was enabled by default and it overrode the `-t` flag, so all packages would be installed in the `$HOME/.local`. The `--system` flag was nominally intended to allow installation in the system package directory, but in practice it was needed to enable `-t`.
- This is fixed for Debian-derived systems that default to Python 3 (eg, Ubuntu 20.04).
- It was never an issue for non-Debian systems (eg, EC2 Linux).

Since you don't seem to be familiar with `pip`, the `-r` argument tells it to use a file containing dependencies, and the `-t` argument tells it to install those dependencies in the current directory (not a great habit, but I don't want to describe virtual environments).